# Which fields in my database diagram should I separate into relation tables?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, diagram, relation

I am struggling with the issue of trying to understand whether or not data should be separated into different tables or kept within the same, in a database logical diagram.

My database is split into 3 parts: users (can be registered users who can post, view or like recipes; and admins who review published recipes and can accept or block users), recipes (which contains data like: dish name, category, dificulty, duration, servings, execution, view count and state) and ingredients.

Recipes and ingredients have a many : many relationship so I have connected those two with a relation table called "Recipe_Ingredient".

Users to recipes has a 1 : many relationship (one user can create many recipes, but each recipe can only be created by one user), but also a relation table connecting them because of the favorites section (i.e. one user can have many recipes as favorite, and each recipe can also be flagged as favorite by many users).

But my actual problem is: I have separated from the table recipes a few fields (see image below for reference) such as Category, dificulty, and state. Is this acceptable or are these fields better off kept within table recipes?

[Photo of what I have so far, for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlN7N.png)

Sorry for the long message. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why did you separate those fields into their own table?

Comment: Difficulties (with *double* f though) and categories look absolutely OK to me. It makes sense to have an extra table for difficulties, if you just want to allow a fixed set of values for that. And specially a description for the difficulty would be redundant if kept in the recipe table. Same goes for categories. But what's the purpose of state? I cannot imagine a state that both users and recipes could have? Maybe you want two different state tables, one for users one for recipes?

Comment: @stickybit Thank you for the input! Sorry for the single f in difficulty, that was a typo. Description in difficulty was a mistake, that table is only meant to contain difficulty rating, but I would like to maintain a fixed set of values for that, yes. As for state, recipes and users don't actually share a state (users can have "blocked" or "unblocked" and recipes "accepted" or "pending"). I just figured I could group them all into one table, but am questioning that decision, now that you put it that way. What do you think? Should they be separated in different tables, the two types of states?

Comment: @Martunis99: Yes, they should be stored different table. If there's only one status table a foreign key constraint in the user's or recipe's table could just check if the status is from the single table but not if it's actually a status suitable for the entity. You won't prevent to store a status of "pending" for a user for example. If there are two different tables for status, then the foreign key would prevent such wrong data.

Comment: @stickybit Yup, that definitely makes a lot of sense. Will proceed as you suggested and separate state into two different tables. While we're at it, I have one other question: it is acceptable for me to have two separate connections between users and recipe, right? One "standard" connection, and one with the relation table "favorites". No problem, there? Overall though, thank you so much for your insight, you have been really helpful!

Comment: @Martunis99: Yes, as they model two different relations: One is for the ownership the other for the favoring.

Comment: @stickybit That's what I thought! Great! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the tables as you have them are mostly fine because as your data increases that's when you see the value of the design.
Here are a few ideas you can use for making these decisions if looking for optimizations:

1. Which tables are simply used for referential integrity with set values that will never change? I would think state and difficulty. The values in the recipe table like state should just show the state value so a lookup isn't needed. Sometimes these types of values that will not change end up in name-value pair tables(fieldname, fieldvalue, fieldtext) and the integrity handled on the front-end. Of course this means that when I look at the recipe table, I can see the difficulty and state right away without going to look up the value elsewhere.
2. If you had to move this into reporting or say analytics, do you have enough descriptors for an end-user to use? This might be a good reason to keep the description for difficulty.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback! So you are saying that state and difficulty are better off kept within the recipes table. So basically, only "values" that can change should be separated (i.e. categories)? That way, we bypass the need to change several records and quickly change that information within its respective table? I can see what you mean, although the same can be argued, to an extent, for state and difficulty (even though, in principle they don't seem as "dynamic" as categories). What do you think?

Comment: Right. Especially if looking for optimizations. Those fields are only used to ensure that bad values do not get into the wrong tables and not necessarily because they are changing and we need to be worried about update and deletes. So my assumption is that difficulty for example consists of maybe five 2 column rows and states represents states in the United States. If there is a rare possibility that these values will change (at all, even once), then you should keep as is. If dealing with multiple countries then it makes sense to keep state.

Comment: Right, I see. So it is all about the referential integrity you mentioned earlier, making sure that the right values are being associated with the proper tables. Makes sense. Actually, "state" is not a reference to states in the US (I am not actually from the States), but rather state of approval (recipes can either be "accepted" or "pending"). In this case, I think I will keep as is because, even though it is unlikely that I will ever make any changes to state, it may happen. Thank you Chuma, you have been a big help! Cheers

Comment: Ah :). Yeah wrong assumption to make there on state. Funny.

Comment: Ahah no problem :) It is actually my fault! I could have posted on the local Stack Overflow plat (Portugal, in my case) but English is not an issue for me, and I figured the amount of knowledgeable beasts around here would be bigger! Again, thank you and have a great week!